# Use .bat to run another .bat with Powershell, with spaces in arguments

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to get a batch file to use Powershell to run another batch file. The first batch is to be run with cmd (i.e. by clicking on it).

a.bat

```
POWERSHELL Start-Process -FilePath b.bat -ArgumentList 'a b','c d' -verb runas >nul 2>&1
```

b.bat

```
ECHO %1
ECHO %2
ECHO %3
ECHO %4
ECHO %*
SET /P=Press enter to exit...
```

I've tried various argument lists, but I can't pass an argument with spaces. Here is what I've observed based on what I've tried. Hopefully at least some of these are wrong.

- All spaces and commas are used to separate arguments. They are retained in `%*` but are not included in any of the single arguments.
- The entire argument list, or each part with spaces, must be enclosed in single quotes if there are any spaces. Other than that, all single and double quotes are stripped.
- Backticks ` are interpreted as normal characters, and do not escape quotation marks.
- Single backslashes crash the script, and double backslashes are interpreted as normal single-backslash characters.

Here are some of my attempts at argument lists which inform the above:

- `'"a b","c d"'`
- `'"a b" "c d"'`
- `` '`"a b`"' ``
- `` '"`"a b`""' ``
- `` '`""a b"`"' ``
- `'\\"a b\\"'`
- `'\"a b\"'` - error
- `` '`'a b`'' `` - error

How can I pass an argument list with arguments that have spaces?

Context: my aim is to run a .bat which calls another .bat with arguments, which then uses Powershell to call itself with admin privileges while retaining the arguments. I've gotten it to work except when the arguments have spaces.

Comment: Do you know that a batch file is a script file which needs a script interpreter which is `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` started with `/D` (optional but recommended) and `/C` and the batch file name `"%~dp0b.bat"`? It would be therefore better using `Start-Process` with `-FilePath `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` and `-ArgumentList` beginning with `/D /C "%~dp0b.bat"` and the remaining arguments passed to `b.bat`. BTW: The file extension `.bat` is primary for batch files written for `COMMAND.COM` of MS-DOS and Windows 95/98/XP. There should be used `.cmd` for batch files processed by `cmd.exe`.

Comment: BTW: The used `Start-Process` with `-verb runas` results in calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw). It helps reading the documentation for this function to understand the options of [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and using correct [quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for PowerShell and `cmd`.

Comment: The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` supports only quoting with `"`. There is no possibility to escape `"` in an argument string being quoted with `"` for interpreting also a space and these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<>|`` literally as part of an argument string by `cmd.exe`. How the arguments after option `/C` are interpreted depending on several criteria is explained by the usage help output on running`cmd /?` in a Windows command prompt window. It general it is much easier to do all with PowerShell and an appropriate script instead of using `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the string value with double-quotes, then use `~` to strip the argument of quotes in the batch script:

```
ECHO %~1
ECHO %~2
ECHO %*
SET /P=Press enter to exit...
```

Then:

```
Start-Process .\b.bat -ArgumentList '"a b"', '"c d"'
```

Alternatively, invoke the script directly and let PowerShell take care of quoting the arguments:

```
# use splatting, let PowerShell handle argument quoting
$batchArgs = @('a b', 'c d')
& .\b.bat @batchArgs
```

Comment: This works when run in Powershell but the first batch is to be run using cmd (by clicking on it). I have clarified this in OP.

Comment: (I mean I have edited OP to clarify it after I saw your answer.)

Comment: @H.v.M. Your description is still a bit unclear - you want `a.bat` to call `b.bat` to call `powershell` to re-launch `b.bat` with `-Verb RunAs`?

Comment: Yes. The example with `a.bat` and `b.bat` is simplified in order to focus on the problem, but `realA.bat` is to be run by clicking on it and uses `CALL` to run `realB.bat` with arguments, and `realB.bat` is to acquire admin privileges by relaunching itself using `POWERSHELL` while retaining the arguments from `realA.bat`. The idea is that `realA.bat` is to be as simple as possible since there will be several instances of it with different arguments.

Comment: @H.v.M. Wouldn't it be simpler to launch a single PowerShell script from a shortcut? Then you'd only need 2 files, and you'd no longer need to mess about with command line quoting

Comment: Perhaps. Initially I just had a batch, then divided it into two to run with different arguments, but then I run it on a different computer and right-clicking "run as admin" started it somewhere in C:\Windows instead of in the working directory. I tried to use Powershell for admin privileges as a quick fix. Figured they'd be compatible...

Comment: @H.v.M. You can set both the required UAC level AND the initial working directory on a shortcut :)